# Running time of this pseudocode

Tags: time, time-complexity

```
1 for i = 1 to n
2    for j = i to n
3       for k = 1 to j
4          statements which take O(1) time
```

Please help me find the time complexity of the following segment of code. Is it O(n^3)? I think not because line 3 depends on line 2. I'm really having a hard time and I need your help. Please provide solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

initial thought:  n*n*logN I think?

Edit: the inner most, k, will hit 1 then next time, 1 and 2, then next time, 1 and 2 and 3...   which is linear... it just stops at a certain interval.  With it being linear, i would naturally say N...

So, after thinking about, O(n^3)?

Comment: Also, you can test this by just taking the code, running it, and then graphing the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it like this:

Take half way in the loop when

```
 i = n/2
for i = 1 to n
    for j = i to n
       for k = 1 to j
          statements which take O(1) time
```

the first one is running

```
n/2 times
```

the second one also runs

```
n/2 times(n-n/2)
```

and the third one also runs

```
n/2 times (1 to n/2)
```

Hence in this case `n/2*n/2*n/2` which is giving `(n^3)/8` which is

```
O(n^3)
```